# line color swapping ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point( data = equip_state_hour_wage,aes(State,Average_Pay, col = "red")) +
    geom_line(data = equip_state_hour_wage,aes(State,Average_Pay, group = 1, col =  "red"),na.rm = T)+
    geom_point( data = nonequip_state_hour_wage,aes(State,Average_Pay, col = "blue")) +
    geom_line(data = nonequip_state_hour_wage,aes(State,Average_Pay, group = 1, col ="blue"),na.rm = T)+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))
```

The graph is showing appropriate results but the color of the lines are swapped. Even in the legend the red is marked as blue. The line/points supposed to be red are drawn blue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the colors via `scale_color_manual`. Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = equip_state_hour_wage, aes(State, Average_Pay, col = "red")) +
  geom_line(data = equip_state_hour_wage, aes(State, Average_Pay, group = 1, col = "red"), na.rm = T) +
  geom_point(data = nonequip_state_hour_wage, aes(State, Average_Pay, col = "blue")) +
  geom_line(data = nonequip_state_hour_wage, aes(State, Average_Pay, group = 1, col = "blue"), na.rm = T) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", blue = "blue")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```